# Group by one column and count the other conditionally - Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a scheme like the following:
     (id int primary key, itemid int, title char(3) )
which is a database of online purchases in MySQL.
Title column can be either 'Mr' or 'Mrs'. I want to see how many men have purchased each item.
for example the following table:

```
(id, itemid, title)
(1 , 1     , 'Mr' )
(2 , 1     , 'Mr' )
(3 , 2     , 'Mrs')
(4 , 2     , 'Mrs')
(5 , 2     , 'Mrs')
```

should result into following table:

```
(itemid, number_of_men_who_purchased)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
```

Most importantly, Note that **if No men have purchased an item, still an itemid is to be listed, and a zero should be put in front of it.** I cannot form a table where this condition holds. But I think it is possible. As you may have noticed, table is not normalized and performance wont be much of an issue here.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group on `itemid` and conditionally sum up. `title='Mr'` returns 1 if true, else 0, so if no men purchased item with ID 2 the result is 0.

```
SELECT itemid,SUM(title='Mr') AS number_of_men_who_purchased FROM <table> GROUP BY itemid
```